# A question about hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This question is from the Qing Liu's book Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves 7.4.10

> Let P(t) $\in$ k[t] be a seperated polynomial of even degree $\geq$ 2
>   over an algebraically closed field k with char(k) $\not=$ 2. Let us
>   consider the hyperelliptic curve X over k defined by the equation
>   y$^2$ = P(t). Show that the following properties are equivalent:
>
> i) There exist A, B $\in$ k[t] such that A$^2$-P(t)B$^2$=1
>
> ii) k[t,y]$^*$ $\not=$ k$^*$
>
> iii) Let x$_1$, x$_2$ be the points of the support of (t)$_\infty$,
>   then the divisor x$_1$-x$_2$ $\in$ Pic$^0$(X) is an element of finite
>   order.

The i) and ii) looks like the Hilbert symbol and I do not know what does the iii) mean,  please help.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about (i) and (ii). In (i), could we not take $A=1$ and $B=0$?  And if $t$ is transcendental over $k$, wouldn't $k[t]^* \neq k^*$?

Comment: Thanks, I doubt maybe there is some errors in the exercise. Now I try to repair it. In the i), it should be "not exist", A and B can not be zero degree. In the ii), t can be not transcendental over k... I have not finished it, please help.